# How to write to contract directly? (other than Etherscan)

Tags: etherscan

I would like to "withdraw" from WETH into ETH: https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2#writeContract

#### But the Etherscan does not work for me right now :(

[image]

Tried running repo: https://github.com/etherscan/writecontract

But a little bit fiddly with ABI, contract address...

...maybe there is another place (another explorer) to "write" to the contract directly?

Answer (score 1):

## MyCrypto

https://chainbulletin.com/how-to-interact-with-smart-contracts-via-mew/

https://app.mycrypto.com/interact-with-contracts

[image]

PS. Etherscan should become a public good, dissolve into DAO, exit to community